# Errors in android project even on newly created projects, Something is not right please suggest

Tags: java, android, eclipse, project, workspace

The below code is the error list i am getting in the android workspace even while creating new  projects

the code is ------------>

```
[2014-11-03 10:25:40 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2014-11-03 10:25:40 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:178: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:182: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:115: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:107: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:126: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:138: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:143: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:132: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:146: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:150: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:154: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:158: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:164: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:168: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:172: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:174: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:97: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:101: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:54: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:338: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:345: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:352: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] 
[2014-11-03 10:25:48 - AndroidTest] D:\AndroidWorkspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:359: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
```

Comment: I think error due to appcompat_v7 have you add appcompat_v7 in your workspace ?

Comment: Have you tried removing appcompat_v7 -> deleting jarlist.cache and then adding appcompat_v7 back again?

Comment: hey @Arnab , i deleted the v4 support compat in my project libs folder and copied one from workspace>appcompat_v7>libs>and copies android support v4 to my project libs file and all errors went away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me after the update.U cant delete the previous installations directly like that.
Try re-installing the deleted packages ( SDK Build Tools) and make sure you are targeting the right version of android with right version of sdk.
**Deleting the sdk after update of new one causes these issues**